# Need help finding the drain current of a jfet

Tags: circuit-analysis, jfet

I have this simple dc jfet circuit (homework):

[image: Circuit]

First of all I had to find the values of the drain and source resistors given the data above, this was pretty simple and I got:
$$R_D=4k\Omega $$
$$R_S=11k\Omega $$

Next, \$I_{DSS}\$ get's doubled to \$8mA\$, now I'm asked to find \$I_D\$.

Using: $$I_D = I_{DSS}\left [ 1-\frac{V_{GS}}{V_P} \right ]^{2} $$

I've found out that:
$$I_{D1} =1.16mA$$
$$I_{D2} =1.0258mA$$

During the calculations I've assumed the transistor is saturated thus:
$$V_{DG} > V_P $$
It seems like both \$I_D\$'s fulfill the above requirement.

How can I tell which one is correct ?

Comment: Have u already checked if both currents fulfill your saturated supposition?

Comment: I have,
I get \$V_{DG} = 5.36v\$ and \$V_{DG} = 5.9v\$ respectivly, they are both larger than \$V_P = -2\$

Comment: Well if you see mathematically , Id is directly proportional to Idss. For Idss = 4 mA , Id = 1 mA . So for Idss = 8 mA, Id = ?? (I think I'm right, just a bit confused why no one else has pointed this out. Feel free to correct me)

Comment: but \$ V_{GS} \$ is also a function of \$I_D\$

Comment: @Mike why didn't you use Rs = 13k?

Comment: I've found out \$ V_S = 1v \$ so I get \$R_S = 11k \$

Comment: @Mike But \$V_S = 3V\$ will also satisfy the current equation. See my [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/162076/27943).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image (*taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFET#/media/File:JFET_n-channel_en.svg)*) below shows the JFET chara. It can be seen that the drain current reduces to zero as \$V_{GS}\$ approaches pinch off (\$V_{P}\$). And the channel is off for \$|V_{GS}|>|V_{P}|\$ and no current flow happens.

[image]

So the transistor is in saturation and the Shockley's equation

$$I_D = I_{DSS}\left [ 1-\frac{V_{GS}}{V_P} \right ]^{2} $$

is valid only if \$|V_{GS}| < |V_P|\$ and \$V_{DG} > V_P\$.

---

Now calculating \$V_{GS}\$ in your case,

**case1:** \$I_{D1} =1.16mA\$
$$V_{GS} = -2.76V$$ 
But \$V_{P}=-2V\$ so \$|V_{GS}| > |V_P|\$ and hence transistor is in cut-off.

**case2:** \$I_{D2} =1.0258mA\$
$$V_{GS} = -1.2838V$$ 
Here, \$|V_{GS}| < |V_P|\$ and hence transistor is in saturation.

So \$I_{D} =1.0258mA\$ is the correct answer.

---

**PS:** You should have faced this problem while calculating the value of \$R_S\$ also.

$$1mA = 4mA\left( 1 + \dfrac{10-1mA\times R_S}{2}\right)^2$$

\$R_S = 11k\Omega\$  and \$R_S = 13k\Omega\$ will satisfy this equation. The value \$R_S = 13k\Omega\$ can not be used because of the same reason discussed above.